# Regular expressions represents the sets provided

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

While I am studying formal languages, I see these questions.What are the answers for them?

a) The set of strings over {a, b, c} that begin with a, contain exactly two b’s, and end with cc.

b) The set of strings of even length over {a, b, c} that contain exactly one a.

c) The set of strings over {a, b} that contains an even number of substrings ba.

Comment: @A.Sh For (a) part, I know that it starts with a^+ and at the end we have (cc)^+.But I can't handle middle.

Comment: Well, consider the following: A string begins with $a$, contains two $b$'s in the middle, and ends with $cc$. Then it's general shape is something like $a?b?b?cc$, where "$?$" may be replaced with any strings consisting of $a$:s and $c$:s. So if you can create a regular expression for the "$?$" parts, you're pretty much done. The key lies in using the Kleene star. Can you solve it now?

Comment: @A.Sh a?b?b$cc where "?" = (a+c)^* , "$" = bc^*a^*c^* , am I right?

Comment: There is a third question mark between the second $b$ and the $cc$ at the end as well, but yes, that is correct. So the full expression should read $a(a+c)^*b(a+c)^*b(a+c)^*cc$. Now, can you solve the other ones?

Comment: @A.Sh Yes, I solved all of them.Thanks...

Comment: Good. I'll give you an upvote as a reward :)

Answer (score 0):

$a)$ The leading $a$ and trailing $cc$ are explicitly placed in the expression:
$$a(a∪c)^∗b(a∪c)^∗b(a∪c)^∗cc$$
Any number of $a’s$ and $c’s$, represented by the expression $(a∪c)^∗$, may surround the two $b’s$.

$b)$ Let $S=\{b, c\}$. Then, in steps:

1. The set of words of even length on the alphabet $S$ is $(SS)^∗$.
2. The set of words of odd length on the alphabet $S$ is $(SS)^∗S$.
3. Therefore, final regular expression is:your language is :$$(SS)^∗a(SS)^∗S∪(SS)^∗Sa(SS)^∗$$

$c)$ The set of strings over $\{a, b\}$ that contains an even number of substrings $ba$ :

$$a^*(b^+a^+b^+a)^+b^*$$